# How does the UML mustBeOwned property work?

Tags: uml

I'm currently studying the [UML superstructure document](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.3/), and I don't understand the modelling of the mustBeOwned property.
In principle, every element must be owned, unless it overrides this default. In the UML superstructure document, only the Package element does this. As far as I understand, this means that only a package can be the top level element.
Now, in the root diagram of the kernel package (p. 25 of the superstructure), it is modelled that a comment is a composite of an element, but it has a multiplicity of 0..1.
A comment is not a package, so it must have an owner according to the mustBeOwned property, but according to the multiplicity, this is not mandatory. Why is the multiplicity not just 1?

Answer (score 0):

In the UML superstructure you have to consider :

- Structural View: Class, Package
- Object Diagrams Implementation :    Component Diagram
- Behavioral View :     Sequence, State, Activity Diagrams
- Environment View : Deployment Diagram

Structural View should have a package at the top for the other you can add this information at the root of the project.

Comment: I am only considering the structural view at this time, but this still means that any element that is not a package, must be owned. So why does the composite relation between comment and element have a multiplicity of 0..1 instead of just 1?

Comment: I use directly the UML metamodel with the EclipseUML open source plugin. It creates my model structure and then I use an UML tool (e.g; Topcase, Papyrus, RSA or Omondo) to extract class diagram views. The reason why this information is not known to me is because I am only a user of the UML specification. I have never really spend time reading the full specification. I can see in the UML metamodel tree the way it is organized and  you need a package for each element. Hope this help :-)

Comment: I get that, every element has an owner, except maybe for some top-level packages. So maybe some attribute is owned by a class, which itself is owned by a top-level package.  
What I don't get, is why a comment (a subtype of element), which is owned by some element, has multiplicity 0..1, instead of 1..1.